# The solutions for $x^x = z, z \in \mathbb{Z^+ - \{4\}}$ are irrational

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-functions

Suppose that the function $x^x = z, z \in \mathbb{Z^+ - \{4\}}$ has rational solutions. Then $x^x = (\frac{a}{b})^{{\frac{a}{b}}}$ where $a$ and $b$ are coprimes. Now let's look at the equation $(\frac{a}{b})^{{\frac{a}{b}}} = z$, clearly $(\frac{a}{b})^a = z^b$, so $\sqrt[a]{\frac{a^a}{b^a}} = \sqrt[a]{z^b}$. We conclude that $\frac{a}{b} = \sqrt[a]{z^b}$, this imples that both sides are rational, but the right side can only be rational if $z^{\frac{b}{a}}$ is rational, since $b$ and $a$ are coprimes, this cannot be true, so the assumption that the solutions are rational must be false.

This is my attempt to prove, it's clearly missing something. Does exist a more "technical" proof of the statement that every solution for this equation is irrational whenever $z$ is different of $4$?

Comment: Let $k$ be any integer.  And let $z = k^k$.  Then $x^x = z$ will have an integer solution $k$.

Comment: "since b and a are coprime"  If $b = 1$ and the solution is an integer this is not an issue.  And indeed $x^x = k^k$ for any integer obviously has solutions.  But if the rest of the proof is correct you may have prove for any integer not in the form $k^k$ there is no rational solution.  I'm pretty sure that's true and your proof may be valid.

Answer (score 3):

$$ 27 = 3^3   $$
$$ 3125 = 5^5  $$

Comment: Not to mention $1^1 = 1$.

Comment: I kind of confused integers with primes. When i saw what i wrote it was too late. there's even a 4 in the title, it's embarrassing to look at this question. I'm sorry.

Comment: @M.Silva I guess the lesson is to try to check statements you come across, perhaps by trying examples. For now, this will often be possible, problems will generally be intended for solution by hand. You might enjoy one I could not do for months https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2895089/matrix-identity-extends-to-real-entries   I even had trouble thinking of a way to investigate as far as true/false. Finally I found a way to do a good example.

Answer (score 1):

Your relation can be written
$$
a^a=b^az^b
$$
If $a=1$, then we conclude $a=b=z=1$.

Let's assume $a>1$. Then $a$ is divisible by a prime and we conclude $b=1$, because no prime dividing $b$ can divide $a$. Thus the relation becomes $a^a=z$, which is certainly possible: just take any positive integer $a\ne2$ and define $z=a^a$.

What is true is that the equation $x^x=z$ has no rational solution if $z$ is not of the form $a^a$ for an integer $a$.